# Am I allowed to enter Poland on French-issued multiple-entry Schengen visa?

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, poland

I am an Indian national and a frequent traveler. I have been issued a Schengen multiple entry visa twice from the French Embassy in Central Africa. I have been to France three times and two times to Poland on same visa. Now I am in India and  would like to fly directly to Poland on the same valid visa. I would like to know are there any issues entering Poland first instead of France?

Comment: Well this is certainly not a dupe to the one suggested by @Karlson as this Q is not about the first trip to the visa-issuing country, but a later trip!

Answer (score 3):

It should be perfectly fine as you have a multiple-entry visa, which you can show to have used regularly without breaking the rules.